# How to config webpack to be able to serve static html file along with react app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, webpack

I'm trying to build a react app with Webpack which reserves some path for HTML static files without importing them into react app, as in the example below.

**Expected Result:**

```
localhost:3000/any/other/path -> load React
localhost:3000/test.html -> load HTML file
```

**Current Results**

```
localhost:3000/any/other/path -> load React
localhost:3000/test.html -> redirect to localhost:3000/test -> load React (Default Route)
```

**Here's what I've tried.**

1. using `html-webpack-plugin` to define another HTML file

   ```
   plugins: [
     ...
     new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
       template: "./public/index.html",
       hash: true,
     }),
     new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
       template: "./public/test.html",
       filename: "test.html",
       chunks: []
     })
   ]
   ```
2. using `copy-webpack-plugin` to copy the HTML file to the build directory.

**Here is my `webpack.config.js`**

```
require("dotenv").config();
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const path = require("path");
const webpack = require("webpack");
const { ModuleFederationPlugin } = webpack.container;
const deps = require("./package.json").dependencies;
const configs = require("./src/configs/build/configs.json");
configs.NPM_VERSION = require("./package.json").version;

const buildDate = new Date().toLocaleDateString();

module.exports = (_env, argv) => {
  return {
    entry: "./src/index.ts",
    mode: process.env.NODE_ENV || "development",
    output: {
      publicPath: `${configs.DOMAIN}/`,
    },
    devServer: {
      port: configs.PORT,
      open: true,
      historyApiFallback: true,
      hot: true,
      static: {
        watch: true,
      },
    },
    devtool: "source-map",
    resolve: {
      extensions: [".ts", ".tsx", ".js"],
    },
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.(js|jsx|tsx|ts)$/,
          loader: "ts-loader",
          exclude: /node_modules/,
        },
        {
          test: /\.(css|scss|sass)$/,
          use: ["style-loader", "css-loader", "postcss-loader"],
          exclude: /node_modules/,
        },
        {
          test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|jpeg|gif)$/i,
          type: "asset/resource",
        },
        {
          test: /\.html$/i,
          loader: "html-loader",
        },
        {
          test: /\.tsx?$/,
          exclude: /node_modules/,
          use: [
            {
              loader: "dts-loader",
              options: {
                name: configs.APP_NAME,
                exposes: {},
                typesOutputDir: ".wp_federation",
              },
            },
          ],
        },
      ],
    },

    plugins: [
      new webpack.EnvironmentPlugin({ BUILD_DATE: buildDate }),
      new webpack.DefinePlugin({
        "process.env": JSON.stringify(configs),
      }),
      new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        template: "./public/index.html",
        hash: true,
      })
    ],
  };
};
```

Comment: Did you use `create-react-app` to initialize your project?

Comment: @Designly Yes, but I tried to implement a micro frontend with module federation, so I switch to manually building with webpack instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because when I run the serve command

```
serve -s dist -p 3000
```

The `-s` will resolve the symlink instead of showing 404. Somehow this option affects my public HTML file. If I revise it, then it works.
**BUT**, this way, your react-router-dom will not work properly as the path that you're not specified in the router will lead to a 404 page instead of a default redirect.

I end up setting up an express server inside my project to serve the static path separately.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a folder in your project root called `public`. Any HTML file places there will be relative to URL root.

Comment: I have a `public` folder in my root but react-router was redirecting it to the default component instead.
FYI, other assets such as image files are not being overtaken by react-router.

Comment: Weird. I use NextJS but I spun up a quick `create-react-app` and put a test.html file in /public, and then went to http://localhost:3000/test.html and it worked.

Comment: Not sure why, but I try new `create-react-app` and repeat what you just did, but localhost:3000/test.html still redirect to localhost:3000/test

Comment: works in this [code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/zealous-nash-p0ubz5?file=/public/test.html) too.

Comment: @taritn are you using `react-router-dom`?

Comment: Yes in my original post, but no in the one I initiated from your suggestion. So may be it’s about version? I’ve to find out.

Comment: For those who are stuck on this, I have the answer to my question. check it out